# How to solve Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(…) in React Native (Android)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I get a problem in react native, I don't know why suddenly I get this problem when develop the app, I try to look for an example but fail all.

The error detail like this :

```
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'LinkingManager' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.
```

Please anyone helpme to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Its for IOS though but you can take help from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713472/invariant-violation-turbomoduleregistry-getenforcing-devsettings-could

Comment: Did you solved this issue. I am facing thais in android debug build?